# mule 3 question regarding payload From third party

Tags: mule, mulesoft

here we're calling  api through  http request connector  by get method and todoSubjectline is The api field name which we're receiving from thirdparty ( "todoSubjectLine" : " Maternity Leave-  Unpaid Optional J( 12/09/2022 - 11/10/2022) and in this I need the data till date only which need to send to the main system

Comment: Please give an example of the expected output for that input.

Comment: And what is exactly the input that you are sharing? Part of a JSON? a Java object?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.